# How to prevent scientific notation from a string generated from "number to string" function?

Tags: c++, string

I have a number_to_string function which converts numbers to string. Now I want to output the resulted string without scientific notation. Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string number_to_string( double value )
{
    string result;
    stringstream convert;

    convert << value;
    result = convert.str();

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    double d = 591284081248903124;
    string s = number_to_string( d );
    cout << s << endl; // why it shows 5.91284e+17 ?!?!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::fixed` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fda16883745df0a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `convert << std::setiosflags (std::ios::fixed);` before line `convert << value;`. And don't forget to `#include <iomanip>`.